# point within a mesh sql

Tags: mysql, mesh, geo

We want to know if a certain point is within a mesh in sql. We also want to know if a point is within two meshes, which one of there are within the other. For example: if we have one mesh covering USA and another covering Texas. If you pass the location within Texas it return the Texas mesh, but if you pass a location in Oklahoma it will return the USA mesh.

Do you guys know how this can be achived and what is the best way to represent these meshes in a mysql table?

Comment: What does a "mesh" consist of, and what does a "point" consist of?  What data do you have at your disposal?

Comment: A mesh consists of an array of cordinates read clockwise, eg: 
[60.470973, 8.470395 - 
60.470402, 8.468442 -
60.471005, 8.464301 -
60.472485, 8.466253]

A point consists of a geoposition: 
60.471661, 8.467305

Comment: Cool, do you already have a data structure in place for this?  Could you post a diagram or description of the tables?

Comment: No i have not, didn't wanna start without doing propper research as I have never done anything like this before. Told the guys at work, but they couldn't figure it out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's pretty hard to answer this based on the information provided, but I envision something like:

- **A mesh table** - defining the boundaries of a mesh and an assignment ID
- **A city assignment table** - that indicates a city is within a given mesh based on both a mesh ID and a city ID--uniquely identified
  by an assignment ID
- **A city table** - defining any properties of a city, including the mesh ID it belongs to--with a city ID

Anything inserting to the city table would determine the mesh it belongs to by evaluating the mesh boundaries (based on its own location), and would assign itself appropriately.

The use case of determining bordering meshes could be achieved either through a direct relationship with bordering meshes, or calculated dynamically based on a side (two corner coordinates) being identical to another mesh.

(this was too long to leave as a comment, so if you'd like additional input, feel free to comment :) )

Comment: @Lars Erik  Or, are you referring to having meshes contain other meshes?  I couldn't understand from your question

Comment: Thanks! When it comes to one mesh inside another i know how to fix that part of the problem.